# React Native : how to change view on onPress event

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i have a button on my first rendered View ( the default View ) , i want to change the View when the user press that button .

i know how to use the `onPress` event but i dont know how should i change the whole View ? im creating another `react.createClass` which has the new render and other stuffs in it but i dont know how should i use it for the `View` to be Changed .

here is my first View ( the Main one ) ( by the way the application name is sess ):

```
var sess = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(

      <View>
        <Button> change view </Button>  //onPress is gonna be here
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

and i want the View to be changed to this :

```
var newView = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(

      <View>
        <Text> the View is now changed </Text>
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var sess = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      viewOne: true
    }
  },

  changeView(){
     this.setState({
       viewOne: !this.state.viewOne
     })
  },

  render(){
    if(!this.state.viewOne) return <newView changeView={ () => this.changeView() } />
    return(
      <View>
        <Button onPress={ () => this.changeView() }> change view </Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var newView = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text onPress={this.props.changeView}> the View is now changed </Text>
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks . that was really a good approach and solved my problem . but just for curiosity isn't there any other and easier approaches ?

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi There may be a slightly easier approach, but it will probably be fundamentally the same as the above. Basically, attaching something to the state or props, and hiding or showing based on that value.

Answer (score 5):

Would suggest you look into the package react-native-router-flux.

On github @  https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Powerful way to lay out multiple views in a project.

For example the render of my app is below.  It supports multiple views (described as scenes) by react-native-router-flux.  The component property is simply your class derived from React.Component.

```
import {Scene, Router, TabBar, Modal, Schema, Actions, Reducer} from 'react-native-router-flux'

  render() {
       return <Router createReducer={reducerCreate} sceneStyle={{backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7'}}>
           <Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
               <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                   {/*<Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
                   <Scene key="register2" component={Register} title="Register2" duration={1}/>
                   <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Replace" type="replace"/>*/}
                   <Scene key="launch" initial={true}>
                    <Scene key="launch1" component={Launch}  hideNavBar={true}  style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
                        <Scene key="privacy" type="push" component={DisplayTextFile} title="Privacy"
                          textFile={DisplayTextFile.PRIVACY} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
                        <Scene key="terms" type="push" component={DisplayTextFile} title="Terms Of Service"
                            textFile={DisplayTextFile.TERMS} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
                        <Scene key="login" type="push"  hideNavBar={true}  component={Login} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
                        <Scene key="forgotPassword" type="push"  hideNavBar={true}  component={ForgotPassword} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
                        <Scene key="pleaseWait" component={WaitWindow}/>
                    </Scene>
                   <Scene key="pleaseWait" component={WaitWindow} panHandlers={null} />
                   <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true} default="feed"  panHandlers={null}  >
                       <Scene key="feed" component={FeedScreen} mainfeed={true} title="Feed" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
                       <Scene key="discover" component={Discover} title="Discover" icon={TabIcon}/>
                       <Scene key="messages" component={Messages} title="Messages"  hideNavBar={true}  icon={TabIcon}/>
                       <Scene key="dashboard" component={Dashboard} title="Profile" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
                       {/*<Scene key="tab4" component={TabView} title="Tab #4" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
                       <Scene key="tab5" component={TabView} title="Tab #5" icon={TabIcon} />*/}
                   </Scene>
               </Scene>
               <Scene key="waitWindow" component={WaitWindow} panHandlers={null} />
           </Scene>
       </Router>;
   }
```